# How do I place an mbox command specifically?

Tags: floats

I have a problem where a flaot (mbox paragraph) is not placed in the new page even when the code is:

```
\newpage
\subsubsubsection{Spell list}
\begin{table}[H]
```

I need a method to make the paragraph not a float.

This is the command:

```
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

The problem comes up when I try to fit both subsubsubsection and the table in the same page. The table is no longer a float so but if there's room in the page before the `newpage` the `subsubsubsection` will go there and not follow the order of the code probably because it's a float.

Comment: How big is the table? Perhaps the `\subsubsubsection` and your `table` doesn't fit together on the same page...

Comment: it's pretty big, but they should fit.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't. We wouldn't know because you didn't supply it. Do you receive any warnings in your `.log`?

Comment: `\paragraph` is a section heading and _never_ floats. `table` is normally a float but you have used `[H]` (presumably using the `float` package) which makes that not a float. The definition `\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}` is however wrong you have a trailing `\\ ` which will generate underful hbox warnings and bad output if followed by a paragraph break.

Comment: please always provide a small but complete document that shows your problem as it is hard to understand your description with no example.

Comment: David's comment is the answer, I think. So It's not at all about floats.
I'll reduce the size of the table.
David if you can write it as an answer and maybe provide also information on a better way to define the command I could mark it as the answer.
As for the table itself, I have many packages and about 1000 lines of code so I reduced it to only the minimal that is necessary to understand the issue.